# Update / Insert records to a table with a MERGE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, merge

I did this 3 years ago with DB2 but can't remember how.

All I want to do is Update/Insert a record into a table.  Rather than test for its existence and changing my DML, I want to do this with a parameterized insert/update(merge) T-SQL statement.  I believe the procedure compiler optimizer will make this the most efficient method.

```
USE [MY_DB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[map_locations]    Script Date: 10/11/2015 9:29:26 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[map_locations](
    [loc_min_lat] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [loc_min_lng] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [loc_id] [int] NULL,
    [center] [varchar](20) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__map_locs__call___5E4ADDA8]  DEFAULT (''),
 CONSTRAINT [PK__map_map_locs__79C80F94] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [map_locations_lat] ASC,
    [map_locations_lng] ASC,
    [center] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Simply put, I want to be able to insert a record into the above table if it does not violate the PK but update it if the record (from a PK perspective) exists.

I have been researching and all the MS SQL examples are for two table merges.  I am passing in a record via parameters.

I am working in Delphi XE10 (not that that should matter) and the database is MS SQL 2012.

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "rather than", I assume you're using Sql Server 2008 or later and are wanting to use its Merge command (apologies for the earlier version of this answer).

Here's a sample TransactSql script (tested and working, but using my table structure) which assumes you know the PK in advance:

```
declare @id int

select @id = 1

merge table1 as dest
using (values (@id, 'name1'))
    as source (id, name)
    on dest.id = @id
when matched then
    update 
    set name = source.name
when not matched then
    insert ( id, name)
    values ( source.id, source.name);

select * from table1
```

From a Delphi app, you'd want to write that as a parameterized query, or, better, a parameterized call to a stored proc on the server.

These days, no Delphi-tagged q about Sql seems complete without a mention of Sql-Injection, but using a parameterized query should minimise the risk of that.

Comment: What is the use of `updlock` hint with no transaction block?

Comment: @kobik:  Yes, I wondered that when I first came across it in a Transact Sql textbook example, c.2000, and imagined the author was assuming that it would get wrapped in an implicit transaction if there wasn't an explicit one wrapping the statement

Comment: You will need a transaction in this case

Comment: @kobik.  Thanks.  Actually, I realised I'd misunderstood the OP's question, so I've updated my answer to use the MERGE command.  Meanwhile, prompted by your comment, I've found something testing updlock which I don't quite understand at the moment.  If I can't figure it out, I'll post a q of my own and post a link to it.

Comment: After your EDIT: I also misunderstood the OP's question. so +1. BTW, have you verified this syntax correct? `update set name = source.name` (rather than `update dest set name = source.name`)

Comment: @kobik:  Yes, I wondered about that, too.  I tested it on Sql Server 2014 before updating my answer:  including the "dest" in the "update ..." provokes an "Incorrect syntax near 'dest'." error, whereas leaving it out does not.

Comment: thanks, that will work and it will be a stored proc.